# What is the difference between WNDCLASSEX and CreateWindow?

Tags: c++, winapi

CreateWindow, Based on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Gives some parameters xposition and yposition, the window size etc.

WNDCLASSEX, Based on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx

Also gives some parameters for the window such as lpfnWndProc (pointer to the process), hIcon (Handle to the class icon).

Besides the different parameters both provide is there another difference between CreateWindow and WNDCLASSEX?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are comparing apples to oranges here. It is not really fair to compare them since they do different things.

Comment: This question is very clear. I don't understand why it was marked as unclear.

Comment: WNDCLASSEX and CreateWindowW are comparable. When you learn the windows api by yourself without using an expensive teacher you will wonder what are the differences. Not all of us had a teacher to clarify this difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx) registers a [*window class*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632596.aspx). A window class is a template, that specifies certain attributes common to all windows of that class, such as the background color, or its behavior (through its window procedure).

[CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) instantiates a window class (specified through the *lpClassName* parameter).

Analogies usually go wrong, but I'll try anyway. In terms of C++, `RegisterClassEx` relates to defining a C++ class, whereas `CreateWindowEx` compares to instantiating that class, i.e. bringing it to life.